# What is the meaning of "decorator" and "got up in"?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, kevin-barry

The following text is an excerpt from ["Wifey Redux" by Kevin Barry](https://electricliterature.com/wifey-redux/):

> I sighed and left the den. The way it worked, Ellie had the use of
>   the sitting room down back of the ground floor; no teenager wants to
>   sit with her parents. She’d had a decorator in – it was got up in like
>   a purple-and-black scheme – and she had a really fabulous Eames couch
>   we’d got at auction for her sixteenth, and I went down there to check
>   on Aodhan and herself.

How to understand the word "decorator" and "got up in"? According to the word "like", I presume there is some resemblance between the decorator and the scheme, but fail to see the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all idiomatic  expressions.

Decorator = a painter, or perhaps an "interior decorator", an advisor in aesthetics of home decoration.

Got up ... in = "the results [of the painting or of acting on the decorators advice] were as follows".  The "in" here is the same as that of "The lady in red", perhaps an extension of the original sense of "clothed in".

like = "as, in my opinion" or just plain "as".

A partial paraphrase: "I'm like, whoah, it was all in black and purple!"
Or more literally, Rand al'Thor's "it was decorated in, like, a purple and black design".

Comment: It's that second "in" which is confusing me. If it just said "it was got up like a purple-and-black scheme", the sentence would seem more natural to me. (Not the OP, but I'm a native English speaker who also found this wording odd after the OP highlighted it.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor 1:  What a long OED entry "in" has, for such a short word!  2: There are regional variations in colloquial speech, and not all native English speakers sound uniformly natural to each other.

Comment: Ahhh, now it makes sense. Just a couple of commas around the "like" would make ti seem more natural to me. My suggested partial paraphrase: "it was decorated in, like, a purple and black design".

Comment: I think a "decorator" is likely to do the painting to the design requested by the customer

Comment: @mikado I think you are right.  It's a dialect difference I was not aware of.

Comment: "get up" in the meaning of "dress or adorn" is mentioned [here](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/got+up). That might be a more direct explanation than "the results of acting on the decorator's advice".